# c# methods that takes an Interface?

Tags: c#

I am new to Interfaces.

I have a lot of objects that I pass as DTOs through my layers to the UI. Some of them are quite complex (Quite a few properties), but I only want to use them, in certain circumstances, in DropDown lists. These DTOs all have an `int Id`, and a `string Description`.

I would like to create a static function that takes a `List<>` of one of these objects, and returns a `List<SelectListItem>`

So, I am trying to use Interfaces for the first time.

I created an Interface:

```
public interface IListableItem
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And then, I assigned that interface to one of my DTO objects I am trying to convert:

```
public class CategoryDto : BaseDto , IListableItem
{
    public int PortfolioId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<ExtendedSubCategoryDto> SubCategories { get; set; }
    public bool IsExpenseCategory { get; set; }

    public CategoryDto()
    {
        SubCategories = new List<ExtendedSubCategoryDto>();
    }
}
```

Then, I created my generic method that takes a list of the category dtos, and will hopefully return a list

```
public static List<SelectListItem> TranslateToSelectList(List<IListableItem> source)
{
    var reply = source.Select(item => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = item.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Text = item.Description
    }).ToList();

    return reply;
}
```

But, when I attempt to use this method, passing it a List, it fails.

```
    model.Categories =
        Translator.TranslateToSelectList(MyService.GetCategoriesByPortfolioId());
```

GetCategoriesByPortfolioId returns a List.

It's failing with the error:

> CategoryDto is not assignable to IListableItem

It's probably a basic Interface understanding issue on my part, but what am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the type returned by `MyService.GetCategoriesByPortfolioId()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your method expects `List<IListableItem>`, you can't pass `List<CategoryDTO>`.

If that would be possible, you could `Add` **different** instances of elements that implement the interface `IListableItem` into a collection that is holding `CategoryDTO` elements, and read them.

Ultimately, that wouldn't make sense.

You can fix it, if you use `IEnumerable` interface. That allows [covariance(going from higher type to lower type in generic type parameter)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx).

The reason it works, is that `IEnumerable` is a "read-only view" of collection, thus you can't really add anything to it - plus what's important, the `type parameter` is **marked** as **covariant**.

```
public static List<SelectListItem> TranslateToSelectList(
 IEnumerable<IListableItem> source)
{..}
```

Comment: *it should be theoretically valid*: it would only be valid for a read-only collection, but not in general. That's why it can be done with an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Thanks Chris! That solved it. I'm not sure why though. Will need to read up, but thanks.

Comment: @Craig A `List<Apple>` can't be cast into a `List<Fruit>` because then you could add a `Banana` to a `List<Apple>`.

Comment: Thanks Chris (For updating your answer and making it clear) and Dirk, for the explanation. Perfect.